# getting an error when using json and http requests

Tags: python, json, http, flask, containers

I have an app which creates a list of random numbers.  As part of a containerised project (i.e. I have to use separate routes and services) I am required to route these to another app which then adds them and (based on a conditional) determines whether they are a jackpot or not.

I have the following code in the front-end

```
from application import app 
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
import requests


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home(): 
    numbers_api = requests.get('http://numbers_api:5000/get_numbers')
    day_api = requests.get('http://day_api:5000/get_days')

    result = {'numbers_api': numbers_api} 
    message = requests.post('http://rollover:5000/get_message', json = {'result': numbers_api})
    

    return Response(f"{numbers_api.text} {day_api.text} {message.text}", mimetype="text/plain")
```

The front-end service works (without the result and message code lines and gives the intended randomised list of 6 numbers e.g. [1, 3, 6, 10, 46, 47].

The message and result lines are intended to send the numbers to another containerised app which has the following code and intends to return whether or not (based on the sum of the numbers) whether is a rollover or not.

```
from application import app 
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify 
import random

jackpot = {
    0: "Rollover",
    1: "No Rollover",
    }

@app.route('/get_message', methods=['POST'])
def rollover():

    result = request.json['result']

    sum = 0
    for number in numbers:
        sum += number
    if sum < 150:
        return jsonify(f"{jackpot[0]}")
    else:
        return jsonify(f"{jackpot[1]}")
```

I am hoping to then send the result back to the front-end and to return a string so ideally the rendered response is.

***[6 numbers], day, rollover or no rollover***

Could someone give me some pointers as to how to get this to work?

Comment: what is `numbers`? you never seem to use the result from your json request

Comment: numbers where, in the for loop?

Comment: the variable named `numbers`

Comment: here  ?result = request.json['result']